# Запятые, сомнения в постановке

Tags: запятые

Скажите, как ставить запятые?

> В скором времени(,) после дуэли(,) Онегин отправляется путешествовать.

Comment: Стилистика никуда. Вот как тут запятые ставить?  Школьники вообще не изучают этот предмет? Тогда при отсутствии чувства языка  нормальное сочинение вообще не напишешь.  Вариант:  В скором времени, уже после дуэли,...

Answer (score 0):

Ни одной запятой не нужно тут! Зачем?!